# How can I use MenuBar.insertMenu method in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to create a dynamic menu in QML, the code is as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: "FIRST"
        }

        Menu {
            title: "SECOND"
        }

        Menu {
            title: "THIRD"
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: myMenu

        Menu {
            title: "ZERO"
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var menu1 = myMenu.createObject(menuBar);
        menuBar.insertMenu(0, menu1);
    }
}
```

The system prompts the following error message:

> QQuickItem::stackBefore: Cannot stack MenuBarItem_QMLTYPE_7(0x28607824d40, parent=0x28606ee4660, geometry=122,0 58x40) before MenuBarItem_QMLTYPE_7(0x28607824d40), which must be a sibling

And the order of the menu is: SECOND, THIRD, FIRST, ZERO.
I really don't understand. Why?

How can I set the correct order of menus: ZERO, FIRST, SECOND, THIRD?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it's much easier to play with the visibility of you menu items

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            id: menu_zero
            title: "ZERO"
            visible: false
            //or

            visible: condition_met
        }

        Menu {
            title: "FIRST"
        }

        Menu {
            title: "SECOND"
        }

        Menu {
            title: "THIRD"
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        if(condition_met)
            menu_zero.visible = true
    }
}
```